# Show SharePoint content based on user login

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm setting up what will be an Internet-facing SharePoint 2010 site. It will be set up to allow anonymous access for the general public, but there is a subsite that should only be accessible to certain users, who would need to log in to access it.

I don't want to show any links to this subsite when anonymous users are browsing, but as soon as a privileged user logs in they should see a link to it somewhere. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something with 'audiences'.

or

Wrap the content in a `SPSecurityTrimmedControl` (this requires editing using SharePoint Designer)

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" PermissionsString="CreateAlerts" runat="server">
  My super secret content.
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

More on the control here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx
- http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-spsecuritytrimmedcontrol/
- http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-spsecuritytrimmedcontrol-revisited/

Comment: I don't think he's talking about content within web parts, I think he's asking about am entire subsite. There shouldn't be any special coding needed to accomplish this. It's OOTB functionality.

Comment: The subsite won't inherit permissions from the main site, but we may not use the quick launch bar for links. We might have a custom header or footer in the default master page that I need to shoehorn in a link to the subsite when a user logs in (similar to having different sitemaps based on user level.) SPSecurityTrimmedControl seems like it might work, I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 2):

That should be as simple as not inheriting permissions from the main site in your sub-sites. Standard SharePoint permissions should control not displaying links to the sub-sites (i.e. on the quick launch bar) for users that do not have access.